# Convert Electret Microphone output to digital data for transmition

Tags: design, microphone, electret

I might be asking a stupid question but....

I was wondering about whether or not there is a circuit to convert the output of an electret microphone to 1s and 0s for transmission. And then we can use the reverse method to convert the data back to voice to play on a speaker.

I have read [this](http://www.pyroelectro.com/projects/pyro_rf_transmitter_27mhz/index.html) webpage, and I found out that we can transmit ons and offs at 27Mhz. So I was thinking about using a microphone to convert real time data from the microphone to 1s and 0s and then to send them out to the receiver to be played.

But the problem is, I don't see a way to convert the output of the electret microphone (for example [this one from sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8635)) to 1s and 0s, WITHOUT any special parts.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

EDIT: Define Special Parts: Pre-made complex circuits counts as special parts. Something like the arduino and raspberry pi all counts as pre made parts. Bluetooth moduels counts too. However, something like an h-bridge motor driver. The 555 Time doesn't count too. Furthermore, diodes, capacitators, resistors and etc. don't count.

Comment: Without any special parts?  Well you can't get some thing different without any other parts.  You need some sort of Analog to digital converter.  The Arduino has some if you want to go that route.  Otherwise there are LOADS of ADCs online.  Just search on digikey.

Comment: @Funkyguy I made some edits, and thanks for the ADC suggestion. However, I wasn't able to find an appropriate one for my purposes. Do you have any suggested ADCs?

Comment: Wait... I'm guessing your trying to send music or speech over the 27 MHz radio link from the article you link to? Instead of the 555's signal?

Comment: @Passerby yes I am trying to send music over the radio link.

Comment: @Fish, aren't you forgetting something? Like channel coding, flow control, receiver synchronization, transmission error correction, error recovery and retransmissions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this old abandoned question as it is too broad and the project is fundamentally not viable.  There will not be sufficient bandwidth legally available at 27 MHz for simplistic digital voice, anything viable there would require a very complex and efficient compression codec, buffer memory, etc far beyond what the asker is willing to consider.  An entirely different approach will be needed - narrowband analog FM, a different frequency band, or a commercial service provider.

Answer (score 3):

Get off you idea of "WITHOUT any special parts". An electret microphone will output a low level analog signal when some bias current is applied to the part via a resistor from a supply voltage. That low level signal then needs to be amplified to some level that is compatible with the analog to digital converter that will be used to produce the 1's and 0's that represent the analog signal level in real time.

Already there are quite a handful of specialized parts just to get off first base with what you think you want to do. If you do not want to have to build all that then maybe you want to look into a USB or BLUETOOTH microphone that already has the essential components in place. Such unit will be spewing out the  1's and 0's in packets of data suitable for transmission to the target connected device.

Comment: Who's on first base?

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 3):

A typical digital microphone circuit is produced of a few parts. Power, Microphone + Analog Pre-amp, a Analog to Digital Converter, and the Microcontroller/Receiver. Often the ADC and Controller are one piece. The Preamp can be as well.

For example, the OVC3860 Bluetooth Audio IC is an all in one IC that provides Mic power, pre-amp and ADC, as well as bluetooth connection.

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that I could just simply replace the button with electret microphone directly. In [this](http://www.pyroelectro.com/projects/pyro_rf_transmitter_27mhz/img/schematic.png) circuit?

Comment: @fish not that I know of. Analog RF transmission is complicated for me. But I answered this before knowing your real question, as the question asked is kinda garbled. Have you tried just building a FM or AM transmitter or are you dead set on the 27 mHz one?

Comment: I am currently dead set to 27mHz

Comment: @Fish there is no way that you will be able to transmit at 27MHz using sound waves.

Comment: @OleksandrR. If you say so, can I get some reasons for why?

Comment: @Fish because the wavelength will be 12.5µm. Air is not a linear medium on this length scale; effects like viscosity become important and it will result in severe attenuation and dispersion of your signal over any significant distance. Acoustic impedance matching is also a problem. It is not physically impossible, but merely severely impractical. If you only want to transmit over a short distance (less than a centimetre), it could perhaps work, if you can find a piezo driver with a resonance frequency of 27MHz. Some more information [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23418/).

Comment: @Fish if you want to transmit only through solids, such as metals (which would block RF transmissions), then these issues become less problematic (although still extremely important to consider). But I see no indication in your question that this is your intention.

Comment: @Fish I think I probably misunderstood your request. If you are hoping for a radio transmission of voice data, rather than a transmission actually using sound, then these comments do not apply. [Here](http://www.qsl.net/va3iul/Homebrew_RF_Circuit_Design_Ideas/Homebrew_RF_Circuit_Design_Ideas.htm) is a good site with a lot of RF circuits described, if you want to build the transceiver yourself.

Comment: @fish, ask a new question, using that circuit picture, and say "I want to use an electric mic to transmit over this 27 mHz carrier wave". That would be a better question.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I am trying to send voice data over not voice waves. Also, I plan to use my toy in a heavily walled area. So ... as i read somewhere, a lower MHz will generally be better at penetrating walls than higher MHz waves.

Answer (score 2):

If you would indicate what sort of receiving setup you plan to use it would guide the answers.

A (continuously variable) slope delta (CVSD) modulator IC (special part) would have been one method in the past but they are rarely used these days. The data is free running or synchronous usually.

An 8 pin microcontroller and bit of code (special part) could generate a chosen digital modulation bit stream. I have used one to convert audio to 115200 bps asynch data with a 6kHz bandwidth. Very few other parts required, just to amplify signal to 0 to 5V for the ADC. You could use any of a number of [modulation schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulation) depending mostly on the type of receiver you plan to use.

There are [duty cycle modulators circuits](https://www.google.com/search?q=ne555%20duty%20cycle%20modulation&tbm=isch) using an NE555 IC that can be implemented but they will not be clocked or synchronised though it might be enough for you

**EDIT:**

The CVSD modulator ICs could often be connected to work in reverse.

A microcontroller receiving data should be able to use a PWM, R-2R or other setup to generate an analogue output after decoding the data stream.

A filter can be used to filter out modulating frequency of a pulse width modulated signal leaving the baseband voltage behind.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do something like a one bit delta sigma converter with jellybean opamps and comparators and a D flipflop plus some sort of oscillator for the clock, nothing special there... You can even do away with the flipflop by doing a self oscillating design in the style of the UcD class D amps (You don't need the power level, but the phase lead network should be giving you ideas).

Conversion back to audio would be a low pass filter on the output of the receiver...

Downside is the Mb/s data rate, but everyone should build their own delta sigma modulator at least once, the things are fascinating.

Regards, Dan.